# UIElements aside Tab Headers

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol, uielement

Is there a way to place something (a custom `UIElement`) in place on the right of `TabItem`s' headers, so that the headers will consider its size.

I feel like there should be a data template for them, but I do not know what to read or how to query google for that.

[alt text http://trotsenko.com.ua/files/sample.png](http://trotsenko.com.ua/files/sample.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to place content in that location, but there is a way.  To do that you'll have to override the default `ControlTemplate` for `TabControl`.

Most system themes put the `TabPanel` (where the tabs are) and the tab contents in a `Grid` like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                          ClipToBounds="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1"
                                              Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0"
                                           Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1"
                                           Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                  Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Margin="2,2,2,0"
                                  IsItemsHost="true"/>

                        <Border x:Name="ContentPanel"
                                BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                                BorderBrush="#D0CEBF"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                                Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Grid.Row="1">
...

...

...
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
...
                </ControlTemplate>
```

So you **could** add another ContentControl to the grid and have it bind to a custom Attached Property.  Keep in mind that the default ControlTemplates also have a lot of triggers which control overflow handling, amongst other things, and you'd have to make sure that your additional UI Elements don't interfere with that.

You should be able to get something like this fairly quickly, though, if you don't have to deal with TabControl orientation or overflow:

[Three TabItems with a Red Border and TextBlock http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3237/tabpanelexample.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3237/tabpanelexample.png)

Good luck!